# How to make links in ajax loaded page load other pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

The problem: Links in dynamically loaded pages aren't loading other pages dynamically.

On my index page I have links like the following:

```
<li><a class="page_one" title="page_one" href="page_one.html">Page One</a></li>
<li><a class="page_two" title="page_two" href="page_two.html">Page Two</a></li>
```

These dynamically load the content within `<div id="guts">` from the external pages into a div with the same id on the index page using the script dynamicpage.js (below), unless javascript is off, then it will simply load the external pages normally.

Here's the javascript:

```
    $(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        $el;



    $(".dyn").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({

                            });
                        });
                        $(".dyn a").removeClass("current");
                        $(".dyn a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

The links on the index page are working great but for instance if I wanted to link to page_2.html from the dynamically loaded page_1.html, page_2 is being loaded normally and not updating the url to /#page_2.html

I've tried changing .delegate to .live, but this stops it working altogether.

Could anyone push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried `$(document).delegate(".dyn a")....` ?

Comment: `$(document).delegate(".dyn a", "click", function() {` seems to have done the trick! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$("#main-content").delegate(".dyn a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

Here's why: your function

```
$(".dyn").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

binds `click` handlers correctly on exiting and new `<a>` elements within the matched `.dyn` elements. So if you were to add new `<a>` tags to the `.dyn` elements, the script would work as intended.

However, the `$mainContent.hide().load(...` method replaces the contents of `$("#mai-content")` with newly loaded content, meaning you've replaced the original `$(".dyn")` so the delegate function is now watching a removed `.dyn`.

Move your delegation match to `$("#main-content")` and you'll maintain an active "live" or "delegate" watcher that will correctly bind your defined click handler to new `.dyn a` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @potench, what you're saying does make sense but I've tried implementing it and it actually stopped it working. You're suggestion in the comment above works great, but is that not good practice?

Comment: Oh hmm. I suppose I'm inferring a lot about your HTML structure based on the above javascript.  Sorry if that didn't work.  `$(document).delegate` is more costly performance wise than isolating to a smaller selection.  But, it's most likely not going to be noticeable.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the help, potench. If you're interested in seeing the html code and possibly suggesting a more efficient way of doing it - I've uploaded a demo [here:](http://ashleybest.co.uk/coming_soon/060712/)

Comment: Hey @AshBestos, I went to your site and using the console added `$("#main-content").delegate(".dyn a", "click", function (e) {
 console.log("1");
 e.preventDefault();
});` and tested by clicking on different tabs so `$("#main-content").delegate....` should work for you and be ever so slightly more efficient

Comment: Sorry to take advantage of your expertise @potench (you're my new hero), but I think I need to do a similar thing for using the play buttons on the ajax loaded pages to dynamically update the player on the index page, but I'm struggling to nail it and I feel like you may know the answer! See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370470/jquery-soundcloud-music-player-how-to-get-dynamic-track-links-in-ajax-loaded-pa) post...